# overloading operator i/o probblem

Tags: c++, io, overloading, istream

I am trying to overload operator >> but I have a big error when I try to compile

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream & is)
{
string str;
is>>str;
vector<Cord> v;
cout<<str<<endl;
bool test=testeur(str, v);
if (test)
{
  for (unsigned int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
    table.push_back(v[i]);
}
return is;
}
```

my main:

```
istringstream tmp2 ( "(0,0) > (0,1)" );
tmp2 >> x1;
```

I get this error: test.cpp:473:9: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘tmp2 >> x1’
test.cpp:473:9: note: candidates are:

now I tried this:

```
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream & is, const CGPS & rhs)
{
string str;
is>>str;
vector<CCoord> v;
cout<<str<<endl;
bool test=testeur(str, v);
if (test)
{
  for (unsigned int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
    rhs. Add (v[i]);
}
return is;
}
```

and I get this error:

> test.cpp: In function ‘std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, const CGPS&)’:
>   test.cpp:448:29: error: cannot call member function ‘bool CGPS::testeur(std::string, std::vector&)’ without object
>   test.cpp:452:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘CGPS::Add(CCoord&) const’
>   test.cpp:452:23: note: candidate is:
>   test.cpp:106:12: note: CGPS& CGPS::Add(CCoord) 
>   test.cpp:106:12: note:   no known conversion for implicit ‘this’ parameter from ‘const CGPS*’ to ‘CGPS*’

Comment: I'm guessing that's a member function. It has to be a free function so the `std::istream &` is the first parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand what do you mean sorry.

Comment: You're now trying to call a method of the CGPS class from a free function, without providing an instance. It should probably be `bool test=rhs.testeur(str, v)`, so you call the method on your instance. Also, you're going to modify the instance `rhs`, so you should pass a non-const reference to the operator.

Comment: Not to criticize, but have you actually written much C++ before? This looks like you're trying to run before you can walk.

Comment: I am a beginner indeed. It seems to work now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `>>` operator has to be a free function, since it's left hand side is the stream.

So you need to implement

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, YourClass& x);
```

The syntax for calling your implementation would be

```
x1 >> tmp2;
```

which looks really strange.

---

Addendum:

You made two errors in your updated code:

1. The `CGPS` parameter can't be `const` (it's the object you're reading into, so you'll be modifying it).
2. `testeur` is apparently a member function of `CGPS`, so you should call it like `rhs.testeur(str,v)`.

Comment: Yes it has to be the opposite thing: tmp2>> x1;

Answer (score 0):

The operator >> function cannot be a member function of the class because the first argument must be the istream rather than this.

Try this:

```
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream & is, MyClass & rhs)
{
    input the data here (you have access to private data)
    return is;
}
```

or if you only need public members of MyClass to access the data you need, you can make it a stand-alone free function in the same namespace.  The declaration would look the same without the "friend".  It should appear outside the declaration of the class, and you probably need to make it inline.

Clarification:   You have (at least) three choices:

- Declare (and define) the function as a friend function.  It is not a class member even
  though the definition appears inside the class declaration.

  - With this choice you have access to private data in the class.
- Declare (and define) the function as an inline function in the same header file as the class(and in the same namespace), but outside the class declaration, and use only public methods on the class to set the values read.
- Declare the function in the same header file as the class.  Define the body of the function in the cpp file.  The difference is that the function is not inline.

For all of these choices, the operator >> function is stand-alone, not a member of the class.

Comment: I updated the code and there is still an error. You mean I have to implement this function outside of the class?

Comment: If you declare the function as friend, it is not a member of the class even though the declaration appears inside the class declaration.

Comment: I had a "const" on the reference to MyClass.  That was a mistake since this function needs to change myclass (I was thinking operator <<, not operator >>)